# applying image using innerHtml Method but its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends here's my code

```
function dropItems(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y)
{
    var html = document.getElementById('dropContent').innerHTML;
    if(html.length<=0){
        html.innerHTML='<img src="images/drag.jpg" alt=" " />'
    }
    if(html.length>0)html = html + '<br>';
    html = html + document.getElementById(idOfDraggedItem).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('dropContent').innerHTML = html;
}
```

I want to to show a image in div when its empty.. but when it receive any data i want to remove that image by using this script .but its not working plz help me

Comment: maybe just a typo, but you forget the ';' at the end of line 5, that could cause your script to stop executing. Please checkout your console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dropItems(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y)
{
    html = document.getElementById('dropContent');
    if(html.innerHTML.length<=0){
        html.innerHTML='<img src="images/drag.jpg" alt=" " />'
    }
    if(html.innerHTML.length>0)html = html + '<br>';
    html = html + document.getElementById(idOfDraggedItem).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('dropContent').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropItems(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y)
{
    var html = document.getElementById('dropContent');
    if(html.innerHTML.length<=0){
        html.innerHTML='<img src="images/drag.jpg" alt=" " />'
    }
    if(html.innerHTML.length>0)html+='<br>';
    html += document.getElementById(idOfDraggedItem).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('dropContent').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = document.getElementById('dropContent').innerHTML;
```

Here your passing the value to 'html'. not the reference of 'dropContent'. So you can't call 'innerHTML' on variables.

//Modified code

```
function dropItems(idOfDraggedItem,targetId,x,y)
{
    var html = document.getElementById('dropContent').innerHTML;
    if(html.length<=0){
        html = '<img src="images/drag.jpg" alt=" " />'
    }
    if(html.length>0)html = html + '<br>';
    html = html + document.getElementById(idOfDraggedItem).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('dropContent').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dropContent may not be empty even if it shows nothing; because, Javascript does not ignore the White-Spacing so there may be a white-space that keep the length bigger than zero.
Here is the solution, using the jQuery library as it has the needed methods to Trim the contents and other things:

```
    function dropItems(idOfDraggedItem, targetId, x, y) {
        var html = $("#dropContent").html();
        html = $.trim(html);
        if (html.length <= 0) {
            var imageContent = $('<img src="images/drag.jpg" alt="" /><br />' + $("#" + idOfDraggedItem).html());
            $("#dropContent").html(imageContent);

        }
    }
```

It worked for me in a test page I created.

The first line gets the html out of the element, second line trims it and thirth line checks if it is empty.
Forth line creates an element with the html string and the html content of the idOfDraggedItem element.
Fifth line sets the html content of the dropContent to the html content of the recently created element.
That's it.

Hope this works for you too.

PS the .html() method of jQuery extracts the innerHtml of the element, if you want the outerHtml, wrap the element in a div and get the .html() from div to get the outHtml of the wrapped element.